# Autocomplete List Fixed Position Browser Resize

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using MVC 5 with Twitter bootstrap. Recently implemented an autocomplete for a list of Cities. The problem is that if I resize the window while the autocomplete list is shown it remains in a fixed position instead of being below the input text field.

Example on this link

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#!zThemeParams=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)

[Image Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uumO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include javascript to detect the browser resize and close the Autocomplete box when that event is triggered:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   $("#myAutoComplete").autocomplete("close");
});
```